# Python function to find the min/max based on single attribute from a nested dictionary structure

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, max, min

The following data representation:

```
[
 {u'0xbd4f1cc0da707c5712651b659b86766ec6f25af5e388fc82474523339dd1da37': u'90000'},
 {u'0x05a04a7bb2500087c14bc89eb6a49cd4c5afcac63270aff2d4508e610f606eed': u'40000'},
 {u'0xc3f68d46b9e462110e4897a41b573a10fef72747fd4c9e8413eb2e4cba0af9b5': u'21000'},
 {u'0x79dcc6ab82b2024a0d4135d4fa3a5cd62ab740f28fffa3fc4dfdb8b00430baab': u'158971'},
 {u'0x034c9e7f28f136188ebb2a2630c26183b3df90c387490159b411cf7326764341': u'21000'},
 {u'0xffda7269775dcd710565c5e0289a2254c195e006f34cafc80c4a3c89f479606e': u'1000000'},
 {u'0x90ca439b7daa648fafee829d145adefa1dc17c064f43db77f573da873b641f19': u'90000'},
 {u'0x7cba9f140ab0b3ec360e0a55c06f75b51c83b2e97662736523c26259a730007f': u'40000'},
 {u'0x92dedff7dab405220c473aefd12e2e41d260d2dff7816c26005f78d92254aba2': u'21000'},
 {u'0x0abe75e40a954d4d355e25e4498f3580e7d029769897d4187c323080a0be0fdd': u'21000'},
 {u'0x22c2b6490900b21d67ca56066e127fa57c0af973b5d166ca1a4bf52fcb6cf81c': u'90000'},
 {u'0x8570106b0385caf729a17593326db1afe0d75e3f8c6daef25cd4a0499a873a6f': u'90000'},
 {u'0x8adfe7fc3cf0eb34bb56c59fa3dc4fdd3ec3f3514c0100fef800f065219b7707': u'40000'},
 {u'0x8b0fe2b7727664a14406e7377732caed94315b026b37577e2d9d258253067553': u'21000'},
 {u'0x244b29b60c696f4ab07c36342344fe6116890f8056b4abc9f734f7a197c93341': u'50000'},
 {u'0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63': u'121000'},
 {u'0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26': u'121000'}
]
```

Is generated from this loop:

```
dict_hash_gas = list()
for line in inpt:
    resource = json.loads(line)
    dict_hash_gas.append({resource['first']:resource['second']})
```

Based on data that looks, *more or less*, like so:

```
{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"} 
{"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"}
```

I've tried to find the maximum value of the second value in each dict, i.e.

```
{"first":"A","second":"LOOKING_FOR_MAX"}
```

How can I access all of the second values (the ones that look like `u'90000'`) from that set of nested dictionaries, record and output the `max` and the `min`?

---

To precisely define terms: In the example up top, i.e.:

```
{u'0xbd4f1cc0da707c5712651b659b86766ec6f25af5e388fc82474523339dd1da37': u'90000'},
{u'0x05a04a7bb2500087c14bc89eb6a49cd4c5afcac63270aff2d4508e610f606eed': u'40000'},
{u'0xc3f68d46b9e462110e4897a41b573a10fef72747fd4c9e8413eb2e4cba0af9b5': u'21000'},
```

I'd like to search on the basis of `u'90000'`, `u'40000'` and `u'21000'`- that's what I mean by "second" value.

The selection of `max` I'd like to make would be on the basis of the number alone, so in that case `u'90000'`.

---

**EDIT:**

Trying to call it in the following way, I generated the error reproduced below:

```
def _main():

    with open('transactions000000000029.json', 'rb') as inpt:
        dict_hash_gas = list()
        for line in inpt:
            resource = json.loads(line)
            dict_hash_gas.append({resource['hash']:resource['gas']})

    pairs = list(_as_pairs(dict_hash_gas))
    if pairs:
        # Avoid a ValueError from min() and max() if the list is empty.
        print(min(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.value))
        print(max(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.value))
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Do you know how to access the `'second'` value in a single `dict`? Do you know how to loop over the items in the list? This seems pretty straightforward...

Comment: in this one ` {u'0xbd4f1cc0da707c5712651b659b86766ec6f25af5e388fc82474523339dd1da37': u'90000'}`, the second would be `u'90000'`, so I'd like to search on the basis of  `90000`

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase so I just tried it out, but I got this error `pprint.pprint(sorted_x = sorted(dict_hash_gas.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: I didn't notice it was a _list_ of 2-element dicts...  Retracting my duplicate flag.

Comment: Do you want the maximum _numerical_ value of those strings?  In your example input, `u'90000'` is the "greatest" _string_, while `u'1000000'` represents the greatest number.  (Also, is that value in base 10 or base 16?)

Comment: I'd like the greatest numerical value yes, that's part of what is causing me trouble

Comment: You say you want the greatest numerical value, which would be `1_000_000`, but you give `u'90000'` as your desired max, which is only `90_000`.  Also, how do you want to handle ties?

Comment: definetly need the numerical value, that was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your data in a tractable form, it's a one-liner.
In this case, since those dictionaries are obviously records of some sort, the ideal data type is either a custom class or a
[`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).
I went with the `namedtuple`, since all the values are atomic and immutable.
(Also, it comes with many handy features like decent `__str__` and `__hash__` methods, and it's more efficient too.)

All of the effort below is in `_as_pairs`, which generates immutable key-value pairs from that frustrating list of one-item dictionaries.
It also converts the stringified integers
(`value`)
into the *actual* integers you wish they were.
After that, using the data is easy.

```
import collections

# FIXME:  Use more descriptive names than "Pair", "key", and "value".
Pair = collections.namedtuple('Pair', ['key', 'value'])

def _as_pairs(pairs):
    for pair in pairs:
        # TODO:  Verify the dict conatains exactly one item?
        for k, v in pair.items():
            # Should the `key` string also be an integer?
            #yield Pair(key=int(k, base=16), value=int(v))
            yield Pair(key=k, value=int(v))

def _main():
    # Abbreviated below, but conatains same inputs as your example.
    dict_hash_gas = [
      ...,
      {u'0xffda...606e': u'1000000'},
      {u'0x90ca...1f19': u'90000'},
      ...,
      ]
    pairs = list(_as_pairs(dict_hash_gas))
    if pairs:
        # Avoid a ValueError from min() and max() if the list is empty.
        print(min(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.value))
        print(max(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.value))

if '__main__' == __name__:
    _main()
```

Output (Python 3):

```
Pair(key='0xc3f6...f9b5', value=21000)
Pair(key='0xffda...606e', value=1000000)
```

I've included a couple suggestions in the comments:

- Is it important that those dictionaries have exactly one item each?
- Should those hexadecimal strings
  (which I called `id`)
  also be converted into integers?

I can't tell what you're using this for, so I can't answer either of those questions.

Comment: cool- I definitely think this is the right approach. I published an update to the OP with the sorry results of my latest attempt- but when I wake up in the morning I'm gonna take another crack at it :)

Comment: @s.matthew.english:  How did you define `Pair`?  Did you change the field names?  The keyword arguments must match the field names.

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking- so I tried to change every instance of `Pair(key=k, value=int(v))` to `Pair(hash=k, gas=int(v))`, is that the right way? That was my guess based on the error message I got when I tried to run it, i.e. `TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'`, was looking for some info about it in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), but as of yet haven't found a solution. that substitution I described ends up like this `print(min(pairs, hash=lambda pair: pair.gas))
TypeError: min() got an unexpected keyword argument`

Comment: @s.matthew.english:  Assuming you've named the fields `'hash'` and `'gas'`, yes.  See the third line in the "[Basic Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)" (look for the comment "instantiate with positional or keyword arguments").

Comment: @s.matthew.english: That second `key` is an argument to [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) (or `max`).  It has nothing to do with the `namedtuple`.  Slow down and _read_ the error messages...  The new error tells you it's coming from `min()`, not `Pair`.

Comment: hmm, so yeah, I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/95ab1ee6cfdf7aedfc8cd66ce00b572f), but now, that seems inaccurate. I'm kind of a novice programmer so, still trying to learn all the ropes- thank you for these insights. so you mean the `print(min(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.value))`, don't change *that* key, isn't it? what about that `value`?

Comment: @s.matthew.english:  That code still has the wrong keyword arguments to `min` and `max` (`hash` should be `key`).

Comment: man, I think I got it :) seems this finally did the trick https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/c7939fc2ce58730d972639040b543654

Comment: what I had to do was leave the first one as `key`, but change the `value` to `gas`, like so `print(max(pairs, key=lambda pair: pair.gas))`

Comment: do you know a clean and nice way to find the middle value as well? is there a function for that?

Comment: @s.matthew.english:  That's another question.  Search for "median" or "mean" or whatever else you consider the "middle" value.  Ask a new question if you can't find it.  (Hint:  `sorted` takes exactly the same `key` argument as `min` and `max`.)

Comment: ok cool, I'll check it out, I was considering to use `from statistics import median`, but it's not working on my python version. I was thinking median when I said middle, so then, for sorted- first I would sort the list, large to small (or vice versa) and then simply output the record at `length/2`?

Comment: so this seems to work `print(np.median( [x[1] for x in pairs]) )`, but ideally I'd like to output the whole value, not just the exact number that is the median

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained to using dictionaries here? A list of tuples might be simpler to use:

```
dict_hash_gas = list()
for line in inpt:
    resource = json.loads(line)
    dict_hash_gas.append((resource['first'], resource['second']))

sorted_data = sorted(dict_hash_gas, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
minimum = sorted_data[0]
maximum = sorted_data[-1]
```

yields:
`('0xc3f68d46b9e462110e4897a41b573a10fef72747fd4c9e8413eb2e4cba0af9b5', '21000')` for the minimum
and
`('0xffda7269775dcd710565c5e0289a2254c195e006f34cafc80c4a3c89f479606e',
 '1000000')` for the maximum

Edit to show example using `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

DataItem = namedtuple('DataItem', ['first', 'second'])

dict_hash_gas = list()
for line in inpt:
    resource = json.loads(line)
    dict_hash_gas.append(DataItem(resource['first'], resource['second']))
```

sorted(dict_hash_gas, key=lambda x: int(x.second))

Comment: man I think I should stick to dict because this is just part of a larger codebase which is all based on dict, I tried the dict thing you suggested but I got the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: I agree, the list of 2-element dictionaries is making this far harder than it has to be.  @s.matthew.english:  If you use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), you will get the best of both worlds --- easy dotted-fieldname access along with easy sorting _and_ much lower memory use.

Comment: how would that look like?

Comment: The key function for the dictionary would return `int(item.values()[0])` for the given *input*.  You could also show key function use for the `max` function.

Comment: The only problem I see using the dictionary like that is unless you are using Python3.6+ (until the dict implementation changes again) there is no guarantee that the value you want will be at any particular index of `item.values()`. Its possible that you could use a separate key function instead of a lambda and find the correct value based upon some pattern that you know and we aren't privy to.